# How can I convert a periodic range into one range

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm searching for a function to convert sound frequency into a light frequency, or in other words a sound into a color.

For the moment I can achieve this by a simple formula that transposes the sound frequency to the light frequency range:

```
const lightFreq = frequency * Math.pow( 2, 40 );
```

Now if I want to have the wave length in nanometers I only need to do

```
const waveLength = 1 / lightFreq / 10000000;
```

One common analogy between sound and color would be to replicate this corresponding wavelength to each octaves. This would imply that if 440Hz is equal to a wavelength of approximately 640nm then the octave which is 880Hz would also be 640nm.

Using the function could look like:

```
soundFreqToLightWaveLength( 440 ) //approx.640
soundFreqToLightWaveLength( 880 ) //approx.640
soundFreqToLightWaveLength( 1760 ) //approx.640
```

waveLength range `[380,780]`

Comment: Can your question be simplified as: how can I convert a frequency to a note and octive? Or are you asking for something more complex than that?

Comment: Hi! This looks like an interesting question, but it's also a bit unclear. Could you please rewrite the question to make it a bit more explicit and focused? In particular the last sentence, *"I'm asking myself if there is a generic way to do this for analog problematics?"*, sounds extremely vague. What are those analog problematics?

Comment: @AndrewParks I'm asking for a generic answer. Let's say rangea = [20, 20000], rangeb=[30000, 40000], rangea is divided by a certain number n and needs to be converted to a value between rangeb.Do you have any other ideas for my title.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JSmith i'm finding it very hard to follow what you just said. What does it mean to divide a frequency range by n?

Comment: @AndrewParks it mean that for example the range let's say [20, 2000] could be divided into 9 ranges for examples.

Comment: @JSmith that's a circular explanation. I asked what it means to divide a range, and you've "explained" that it means to divide the range into many ranges.

Comment: @AndrewParks well sorry for this.This sounds clear what a division is. For example same note can be in different range so what I've deduced is that you take a global range and then divide it into many sub-ranges which contains same set of notes? Please tell me if that's unclear

Comment: All semitones are 12th root of two apart in equal temperament. so if your tuning note is A440 then every other note should be measured as n = number of semitones above or below A440 and then the frequency of that note is `440 * pow(2.0, n/12.0)`

Comment: "As you might now, notes are periodic so you could have same note within different ranges". Do you mean that a note has a frequency representing a periodic waveform? Or do you mean that a note exists in multiple octaves? It's still very difficult to understand what you are talking about. What does a range represent?

Comment: @AndrewParks yes I'm trying to say that same note can appear in different octaves

Comment: So what does a "range" mean? Is it two frequency values that represent the beginning and end of a single octave? Will the range always be exactly one octave or an integer multiple of octaves? Maybe your question would be clearer if you wrote a worked example of an input and output for your algorithm, and explain it in in terms of notes and octaves

Comment: @AndrewParks sure I'll do this tommorow.Best

Comment: @AndrewParks I've completely changed my question please tell me if it's clearer now?

Comment: Since "notes are periodic", you might want to map them to a circular colour-scheme, such as https://c8.alamy.com/comp/M0TW8X/gradation-of-colors-in-the-circle-M0TW8X.jpg . So, your question could be solved into two parts: (1) Find a circular colour-scheme; (2) Map notes to the circle. For (2), you can use the formula `frequency = 440 * Math.pow(2, angle)` if angle is normalised between 0 and 1, and the inverse formula `angle = Math.log2(frequency / 440) % 1`

Comment: Your question is starting to make a lot more sense. However, is it really a wavelength of light that you want? Perhaps it is, but I'm guessing it's more likely you want to end up with an RGB color code?

Comment: @AndrewParks I have the Wavelength to rgb function. What I need is a function that fakes octaves on the light spectrum so I can then convert them back to RGB.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to divide a frequency range into 9 divisions you will have to find the 9th root of the factor from lower to higher frequency:

```js
let a=20,b=20000,n=9;
const fact=Math.pow(b/a,1/n);
console.log(a);
for (i=0; i<n; i++) console.log(a*=fact)
```

**Update, referring to the updated question:**

The following snippet translates sound frequencies to light frequencies with an equivalence of 440HZ = 640nm. Within one octave: the higher the sound pitch, the shorter the wave length will be:

| sound frequency / Hz | wave length / nm |
| --- | --- |
| 440 | 640 |
| 660 | 426.6666666666667 |
| 879.9999 | 320.0000363636406 |
| 880 | 640 |
| 1320 | 426.6666666666667 |
| 1760 | 640 |

```js
let a=20,b=20000,n=12;

const A=440, lnA=Math.log2(A)%1;
const L=640; // base wave length

if(1)for (let n=35,f=20,f1=20000,fact=Math.pow(f1/f,1/n);n-->-1; f*=fact) {
 let l=(lnA-Math.log2(f))%1;
 let wl=Math.pow(2,l)*L // light wave length in nm
 console.log(f,wl)
}
```

The snippet goes throught the frequency range 20 ... 20000Hz in 35 steps (this can be changed to any value). The light wave lengths are mapped only for the fractional part (`l=(lnA-Math.log2(f))%1`) of the frequencies as the will repeat in each octave.

**Clarification/question**
Looking at OP's latest comment I now assume that the wave-length calculations should be done according to the following diagram:
[image]
In the above example we can see that the whole frequency range (from lower value f0 to higher value f1) has been divided into 6 divisions (instead of octaves!), within each of which the sound frequencies will be mapped to the wave length in the range defined by wl0 (longest wave length) and wl1 (shortest wave length).

OP, is that what you had in mind?

If so, then the following would work for you:

```js
function calcWaveLength([f0,f1],[wl0,wl1],n){
 const lf0=Math.log(f0), lfstep=Math.log(f1/f0)/n,
       lwl0=Math.log(wl0), llrange=Math.log(wl1/wl0);
 return function(freq){ // return the actual calc-function here
  lf=Math.log(freq)
  return Math.exp( lwl0 + (lf-lf0)/lfstep % 1 * llrange )
 }
}

// set up the calc function (once) for each frequency range:
const calc=calcWaveLength([20,20000],[640,460],3);

console.log("frequency,  wavelength");
// test for the following frequencies:
[20,35.56558820077846,63.245553203367585,112.46826503806982,199.999,
 200,355.65588200778456,632.4555320336758,1124.682650380698,1999.99,
 2000,3556.558820077845,6324.555320336758,11246.82650380698,19999.9,
 20000].forEach(f=>
  console.log(f.toFixed(3),calc(f).toFixed(3))
)
```

The snippet calculates what the diagram  demands, but the result is something like a sawtooth wave function, having sharp inclines at the end of each division:
[image]

Comment: n=12 might be a more comprehensible example than 9 in the western world.  For example, a piano scale is typically divided into 12 equally spaced _semitones_.

Comment: In western music the octave is usually subdivided into 12 equal parts ("well tempered" semitones), resulting in a factor of `Math.pow(2,1/12)` (=1.059463094) between them.

Comment: this is not exactly what I'm asking for but anyways I'll take inspiration from this answer

Comment: @CarstenMassmann thank you for your time, I've completely changed my question maybe you'll have a solution and find it clearer.Best

Comment: not sure how to get the good result with your algorithm, basically I need 4 arguments which is ( frequency, rangeA(periodic), rangeB(output range),n (number of division)) the division should include that it's a logarithmic division.Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I'll take a deeper look, test it and get back to you

Comment: Thank you, I know it's the way I've asked you and your solution is great and works well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// outputs a number between 0 and 1, depending on whether the pitch
// is at the lower or upper end of an octave
// each semitone will be 1/12th of the way between 0 and 1
// the octave starts with an A note. Change the number 440
// to the frequency of another note if you want the octave
// to start at a different note
function freqToOctavePosition(freq) {
  return ((Math.log(freq/440)/Math.log(2) % 1) + 1) % 1
}

// linearly converts the position within the octave to a position within a range
function freqToRange(freq, rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  return (freqToOctavePosition(freq) * (rangeEnd-rangeStart)) + rangeStart
}

console.log(freqToRange(262, 400, 700))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll test this and get back to you when tested

Comment: If I was calling it "OctavePosition" I would probably map to a number between 0 included and 12 excluded, rather then between 0 excluded and 1 included.

Comment: @Stef I've mapped to the range 0 inclusive to 1 exclusive. I agree it would make sense to do 0->12 if this were a standalone method, but in my code it's only a helper method, and I'd have to multiply by 12 and then divide back by 12 again when mapping to a range if I made the helper method do that